# In an Excel pie chart, how to represent one value on a pre-set range of value

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-office-2021

I an Excel 2021 spreadsheet, I have a serie of values between 1 and 9 in one of many columns of a table.

With a pivot table, I get the average of those numbers that I can then filter. But the issue would be the same with any way to average those numbers.

If I make a pie chart with that number I, of course, get a full circle. What I would like is to show that value between 1 and 9. 1 beeing an empty circle and 9 a full one.

The manipulation for now is to add a cell where I do `9-average value` so that I can put both value on the chart but I wonder if there is a better way to do it.

Left bad - Rigth good but not fully automatic

[image]

Edit : [Example file](https://easypro-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/ar_easy-pro_be/EcoDHm9PYrpDk-fZ0mWzuGABYvRHH360YmASaqnMjoP03w?e=dT9cSD)

Comment: ,,, please [edit] the post & share some sample data with us will help us to first understand then fix it ☺

Comment: Could you please tell us how did you get the 9-average value? Thx ~

Comment: Edited. The 9 - average comes from the fact that 9 is the highest value possible. So, the value from that subtraction is exactly what the pie chart needs to represent the average value properly. At an average of 9 we get a full circle and at an average of 1 the circle is close to empty.